# $ in formula doesn't stay fixed when pasting

Tags: excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZScq.png)

When I try to drag out the formula in the D column it copies the formula except it doesn't keep the d8 fixed in the other cells. Instead it uses d9 d10 d11 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to lock the row `D$8` or lock the cell `$D$8`. Probably you want the latter one.